# Jackson parsing object of many probabilities but same property name

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson library in my Android project for parsing json responses.

In my case, the returned json array consists of objects of different structure each. I've created 3 VO classes, but I wonder if it is possible to tell jackson to try them on by one until any success.

The following could solve the problem, but it's forbidden, the same `@JsonProperty` but many possibilities:

```
@JsonProperty("Object")
public Class1 object1;
@JsonProperty("Object")
public Class2 object2;
@JsonProperty("Object")
public Class3 object3;
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to write a custom deserializer. You can find information on that here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Official docs are here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers

*Alternative*:

If the 3 objects are related to each other by implementing a common interface, you can do this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public interface MyObjectInterface {}
```

But then you will need to adjust the JSON to include the `@class` property. You did not state if that is possible or not.

*Alternative 2*:

If you already have a `type` property, you can do this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    {@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyObject1.class, name = "OBJECT_1"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyObject2.class, name = "OBJECT_2"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyObject3.class, name = "OBJECT_3")}
)
public interface MyObjectInterface {}
```

Comment: I have a flag called `type` beside my anonymous object, it decides what type the object is. Can it help?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer to show how you can do it.